# XML reader and Data updating, Timestamp

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, atom-feed

As an experiment, By following some tutorials I created a Twitter reader application with refresh button. Everything works fine and when I hit refresh button application refreshes the list without any problem.

Then I copied the same XML file (http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?rpp=25&&q=%23WP7) from twitter.com and Uploaded it to my server. At the beginning application works fine and reads the feed from my server but Refresh button doesn't work Although I update the XML with some entry changes.

I was planning to host some XML files in my server for my Application by using the same Twitter app. But I couldn't understand the reason of this problem.

What am I missing?  Do I need to give some permissions to files in my hosting or maybe changes in Cpanel?

**Solution**
When I add the following code into htaccess file in my server, Everything worked very well.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl|atom)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Without having *any* clues as to what's going on, it's impossible to say. Surely you have more information than "Refresh button doesn't work" - have you tried debugging into it? Are you getting the fresh data but then failing to parse it? Seeing stale data from a cache? What happens if you run Wireshark on the machine with the emulator to see the network trace?

Comment: I installed and run Wireshark. When I use original url, application sending querry to twitter.com. But when I use the url in my server, application is not sending any query to server. It is odd

Comment: Well it's going to be hard to diagnose that without seeing *any code whatsoever*...

Comment: BTW, you don't need "C#,WP7" in your title. We've got tags for that on [SO].

Comment: Yup, thanks for that. I also added timestamp I think thats the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server might have cached your original file. Unlikely but could happen. Use fiddler to see what is beign served and send us more information if you don't get it working.

Comment: Hi, I tried with fiddler it has really useful and clean interface. Anyway, When I target to twitter.com in cache it says "max-age=15, must-revalidate, max-age=300  Expires: Tue, 16 Aug 2011 07:03:03 GMT". but when I use the file in my server. Cache is empty.

I guess this is causing the problem. How can I change it?

Comment: That sound like correct behavior. You don't want to cache on your own server. At least not when you are testing and updating data. Try accessing the data directly from your browser and see if you get the updated data or not. This will make sure your file is updated correctly. Press CTRL-R when you refresh the data in your browser. I think you have to have a closer look at Fiddler and see what data is send on the different requests. Start by checking if the (file)size of the XML data is bigger on your second (updated xml) request.